# Problema No IP do Servidor

Tags: php, apache, servidor, ip

Coloquei Cloudflare no meu sistema, mas ele está fazendo o papel de um "proxy reverso por conta do DNS da CDN".

Mas quando eu dou um `ping -t meusiteaqui.com` ele retorna o endereço IP verdadeiro do servidor, mas em requisição ele está com o proxy da Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

Já que o Cloudflare está atuando como *proxy*, o IP do usuário que está acessando a página é sobrescrito pelo IP da Cloudflare.

---

Do [Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14985633/7445826) *(tradução livre com algumas modificações)*:

Variáveis extras do servidor disponíveis pela Cloudflare para esses propósitos são:

- `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]` ⇒ IP real do usuário (**isso é o que você quer**);
- `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]` ⇒ país do usuário;
- `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_RAY"]` ⇒ [saiba mais aqui](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169746-What-is-the-CF-RAY-header-);
- `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_VISITOR"]` ⇒ ajuda a determinar se o protocolo é `http` ou `https`.

Você pode, então, usar assim:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
}
```

Ou acessar diretamente:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]
```

Note que se você fizer isso, é importante verificar que `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` contenha o IP verdadeiro da Cloudflare, já que qualquer um pode modificar o cabeçalho se estiver capaz de conectar-se diretamente ao IP do servidor.